# When a cost functional is strictly convex?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, optimal-control, nonlinear-analysis

Let $l_1:H\times X\to \mathbb{R}$, $l_2:V\to \mathbb{R}$ and $L:[0,T]\times H\times H\times X\to \mathbb{R}$. Let $J$ be a cost functional given by
$$J(f,g,u,u')=l_1(u(T), u'(T))+l_2(g)+\int_{0}^{T}L(t,u(t),u'(t), f(t))dt.$$
What is more $L(t,v,w,\cdot)$ is convex for all $t\in [0,T]$, $v\in H$, $w\in H$.
When the cost functional $J$ is strictly convex??? I think I have to assume that $l_1$ and $l_2$ are convex and $L(t,v,w,\cdot)$ is strixtly convex for all $t\in [0,T]$, $v\in H$, $w\in H$. Am I correct? Can I achive strict convexity of $J$ in a diffrent way?

Comment: I was also thinking that we may assume that $l_1$ and $l_2$ are convex. If in addition one of the functionals $l_1$, $l_2$ or $L(t,v,w,\cdot)$ is strictly convex, then  so is $J$.

Comment: sum of convex functions is convex [ref1](http://www.princeton.edu/~amirali/Public/Teaching/ORF363_COS323/F14/ORF363_COS323_F14_Lec6.pdf), [ref2](https://www.quora.com/Is-the-sum-of-convex-functions-convex). Is that what you are after?

Comment: Sum of convex and strictly convex is strictly convex